# É impossível fazer trucate a uma tabela com foreign keys mesmo estando vazia?

Tags: mysql

Considere a tabela "A" e "B".

A tabela "B" possui uma foreign keys referente a tabela "A".
A tabela "A" não possui nenhuma foreign keys.
Nenhuma das tabelas possuem registros.

Ao tentar fazer um trucate a tabela "A", o seguinte erro é retornado:

> Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`bd`.`B`, CONSTRAINT `FK_1E45D7B68A6FD59C` FOREIGN KEY (`a_id`) REFERENCES `bd`.`A` (`id`))

Se não existe nada nas tabelas, porque ocorre o erro?

Comment: Por que você quer truncar uma tabela vazia?

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu é um script automático de importação, se algo corre mal, o script volta a ser executado e todos os registros inseridos são apagados. Não coloquei isso na pergunta porque não ajuda a resolver o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apesar de não haver motivos para se querer truncar uma tabela vazia, o erro acontece porque `truncate` é diferente de `delete`. Como você está usando chave estrangeira, é provável que esteja usando `InnoDB`, o que torna o `truncate` um processo ainda mais peculiar.

Quando você escreve um `TRUNCATE table1` no `InnoDB`, ele automaticamente tenta dar um `DROP table1` e depois recria-a. Mas é impossível excluir uma tabela que é referenciada por chave estrangeira.

Se você só quer truncar a tabela para poder voltar o auto_incremento para 1, você pode

```
ALTER TABLE tabela1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

Se a tabela estiver vazia, como você disse, isso funcionará perfeitamente.

Comment: Utilizo um programa que faz isso, se houver problemas na importação, ele faz um truncate e voltar a importar a tabela para manter os ID's corretos. O problema foi resolvido de outra maneira, uma vez que é possível configurar o sistema para utilizar "transactions", assim só grava se correr tudo bem.